# How do I detect that the ESC key is pressed using Lotus Notes?

Tags: lotus-notes

When a user presses the ESC key, I need to display a prompt.
How can I do this in Lotus Notes client?

Comment: a messsage like "Are you sure you want to use Lotus Notes?"

Comment: @Mitch +1. Really why Lotus notes in 2011 ?

Comment: @Mitch- Any message just to figure out.

Comment: @user335160
: I'm sorry I was attempting humour. I have an extreme dislike of Lotus Notes. It's basically poo.

Comment: @Mitch- I dislikes Lotus notes too, but for the reason that our client is a big fan of lotus notes, then we have to accept it, were doing business here. For your information I am a certified .NET developer.

Comment: @user335160
: My commiserations.

Comment: I think everyone has heard it by now. Lotus notes sucks.  Let's move on.

Comment: @skaffman. This question has been significantly modified from it's original intent. I believe the question originally asked for how to trap and ignore the ESC key if pressed in the Lotus Notes client. Not just how to display a message when the user presses the escape key. The currently accepted answer does not fit the question. Can someone please moderate here please ?

Comment: @Mitch I'd be very interested to hear what your specific problems with Lotus Notes are? The fact of the matter is that Lotus Notes/Domino is an extremely useful, valuable, powerful and robust software platform when used correctly. People are all too quick to jump on the "I hate Notes" bandwagon without any real reasoning as to why.

Comment: @Mitch - Thanks Mitch for that extremely insightful and well thought out assessment. If it's such a terrible platform, can you give me 3 examples of what you feel are the main pitfalls with Lotus Notes and/or Domino?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you elaborate? Is this for one application, one form or the whole Lotus client? Why would you want to disable the esc key?

In the Queryclose event you can get a handle to the close event. Continue = false will prevent the form from closing:

```
Sub Queryclose(Source As Notesuidocument, Continue As Variant)  
  msgbox "the message" 
End Sub
```

Comment: @jasper- this will applies only for only one form. the users wants me to disable this, to avoid the accident unload the form, eventhough it will prompt for saving the document. is they a way to disabled the esc key in client?

Comment: There is no good way to disable the esc key (unless you are willing to damage some keyboards..). However why not catch the QueryClose event and present a message to the user?

Comment: The esc button is just one of the methods to close a form. I do not know if there is a way to detect that esc was used to close it. Others have tried: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/46dom.nsf/search?SearchView&Query=disable%20AND%20esc%20AND%20key&SearchOrder=3&SearchMax=0&SearchWV=FALSE&SearchFuzzy=FALSE&Start=1&Count=100 . Catching the general close event and deal with that event is probably the best you can do.

Comment: @Jasper- thank you for the link it helps me a lot. I created a different solution but not contented with the outcome. I hope somebody will help me regarding this problem. Is there a possibility to prompt a message when closing the form?how?

Comment: @Jasper Although the QueryClose event is your only option, it doesn't really address the problem in a way that ignores the ESC key. Please see my answer and review.

Answer (score 0):

### ** The original question changed (by a moderator) from it's original intent, which asked to detect AND ignore ESC key press in Lotus Notes. **

You need to use the "QueryClose" event (as others have mentioned), but how do you identify a "legitimate" way to close the form ? We need some logic to distinguish between someone actually clicking a button to "legitimately" close the form, and if someone hits the escape key or the "X" button in the window bar.

So, you need to use 2 form events, and an action button to do this.

In the QueryOpen event of the form

```
Sub Queryopen(Source As Notesuidocument, Mode As Integer, Isnewdoc As Variant, Continue As Variant)
    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Call session.SetEnvironmentVar("CloseDoc",0,True)
End Sub
```

Your QueryClose event needs to look like this

```
Sub Queryclose(Source As Notesuidocument, Continue As Variant)
    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim iCloseDoc As Integer
    iCloseDoc = session.GetEnvironmentValue("CloseDoc", True)
    If iCloseDoc <> 1 Then
        continue = False
    End If
End Sub
```

And you need to have an action button called "Close", on the form with this in it.

```
@SetEnvironment("CloseDoc";"1");
@PostedCommand([FileCloseWindow])
```

The LotusScript alternative looks like this

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)
    Dim ws As New notesUIWorkspace
    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Call session.SetEnvironmentVar("CloseDoc",1,True)
    Call ws.CurrentDocument.Close
End Sub
```

Now what's going on ? When you open the form, I set an environment variable for "CloseDoc", (QueryOpen event). If the user hits the "ESC" key or even clicks the "X" on the form to close the window the QueryClose event triggers.

When a request to close the form is detected, the QueryClose event then runs. I retrieve the "CloseDoc" environment variable which, in this case is still 0 (zero). If it's not equal to 1 then the close form will be aborted. You can add a messagebox there if you like.

Now the only way for the user to successfully close the form is for them to press the "Close" button. Which first sets the CloseDoc environment variable to 1, then call NotesUIDoc.close(). Although I am not a big fan of environment variables, it is handy in the case as you are able to record user activity without modifying the current document or another document. (That would be even messier, because you would have to clean up temporary documents, or you are forced to make changes to the document which won't work if the user only has reader access to the database or the current document).

This is relatively clean as the control is managed via a discrete envrionment variable that adds no overhead to the database performance and will not get in the way of any other functionality of applications. Some suggestions in the comments advises the use of global variables instead of environment variables and this quite is appropriate if you're using LotusScript exclusively, but if you have a mixture of formula and lotusScript, environment variables are common to both. But it's upto the developer to determine which.

This is one way I have over the years forced the user to click a specific button to close the document, and ignore "ESC" keys or the "X" button int he form window bar without any annoying messages and is free of performance issues.

Comment: The code above will work fine although I would us a global variable in the Lotusscript instead of an environment variable. The Queryclose event will be triggered for any way the form will be closed, so also f4 or File-close. You have added a flag to check if a button was pressed that initiated the close.

Comment: Another issue is the silent failure of the action. In the example the user will hit ESC, maybe F4 or the X, and nothing will happen. If it is a must that the button is pressed, I would tell the user. And what if there are no changes at all, why not just close the form in that case, as expected UI behavior would be.

Comment: @Jasper. Yes a global variable declared in the form would be a cleaner solution, however this solution allows for Formula or LotusScript, thus the usage of environment variables as it's common to both languages. If you're using formula, global variables cannot be used. Just demonstrating how to have as many options as possible. But if you're just using LotusScript, then a global variable would be most appropriate.

Comment: @Jasper Re: Silent failure. I have mentioned in the original answer that you can include a messagebox, but it's not in the code sample. It's upto the developer to determine whether or not silent failure or a message is required. Once you have control of the form, adding messageboxes or not is merely a preference for the implementation. At least, though this solution would in fact stop usage of the ESC key or "un-authorised" means of exiting the form, rather than just a messagebox which still let's the user close the form by the escape key

Comment: Moderators. This question was modified singificantly from it's original intent. I don't believe this is correct moderation of the question, as the asker has not indicated this is what he/she wants.